# Avoiding malloc/free Overhead in structure allocations in C

Tags: c

I am reading and experimenting pointers from this book,

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028000.do

In chapter 6 of this book under **Avoiding malloc/free Overhead** heading
author is suggesting how to avoid malloc/free overhead when doing lots of structure memory allocations/deallocations.

Below is the way he wrote the functions,

```
#define LIST_SIZE 10
Person *list[LIST_SIZE];

void initializeList() 
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<LIST_SIZE; i++) 
    {
        list[i] = NULL;
    }

}

Person *getPerson() 
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<LIST_SIZE; i++) 
    {

        if(list[i] != NULL) 
        {
            Person *ptr = list[i];
            list[i] = NULL;
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    Person *person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    return person;
}

void deallocatePerson(Person *person) 
{
    free(person->firstName);
    free(person->lastName);
    free(person->title);
}

Person *returnPerson(Person *person)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<LIST_SIZE; i++) 
    {
    if(list[i] == NULL) 
        {
            list[i] = person;
            return person;
        }
    }
    deallocatePerson(person);
    free(person);
    return NULL;
}
```

What I understood from his code, that he creates a memory pool array, pointing to **struct person** type and then initialize each array element with NULL.

Next we will get a memory from pool using **getPerson** function. This function, checks against **!=NULL** which I think will fail every time. So again it will be same, as doing malloc and memory is not getting assigned from the pool anytime.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Is this the way to handle overhead ?
3. What should be the correct way to do it? Any source/link would be appreciated.

Comment: In most (but not all) cases, `malloc` is fast enough (e.g. much less than a microsecond on my PC). I would suggest benchmarking before making such an optimization.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How to benchmark?

Comment: That is a very different question, and is operating system specific and compiler specific. Perhaps you could use [`clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) in your code. On Linux you might also use [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), [perf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html), [gprof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) etc etc... See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: But these functions will add to the overhead too. Isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Next we will get a memory from pool using getPerson function. This function, checks against `!=NULL` which I think will fail every time.

The check will fail every time as long as you continue calling `getPerson` repeatedly. However, if you do a mixture of `getPerson` and `returnPerson`, some `NULL` checks will succeed, because `returnPerson` puts non-`NULL` values into the array.

This observation is key to understanding the approach: the array serves as a small temporary storage for `struct Person` blocks that have been allocated with `malloc`, but are no longer in use. Rather than calling `malloc` again, your code grabs an available block from this special list, if there is one available.

In situations when you make thousands of allocations, but never keep more than `LIST_SIZE` objects active at any given time, the number of `malloc` calls is limited to `LIST_SIZE`.

> Is this the way to handle overhead?

This is a variation on using lookaside lists, an optimization technique so important that Microsoft created [an API for its use in driver code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-lookaside-lists). A simpler approach would use `Person *list[LIST_SIZE]` as a stack of released blocks, i.e. with the index of the last released block and no loop.

Another approach would be to set up a linked list of such blocks, reusing the memory of the block itself to store the `next` pointer. This technique may be too complex for an introductory boo, though.

Comment: So the whole point of this approach is to save 10 allocated blocks while deallocating, thus reducing overhead of 10 memory allocations at further point in time.

Comment: @nikhilchaubey Why, as long as you never have more than ten items active at any given time, this technique reduces the overhead on millions of allocations. For example, you get ten items, then return ten items, and you repeat this "get ten / return ten" cycle a million times. Instead of ten million allocs and ten million frees you have ten allocs in total; all other "gets" came from the `list`.

Comment: Thats true. In general this technique saves on 10 allocations only. Out of 1000, 10 will be saved, rest 990 will have overhead allocations/deallocations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all what your writer referring to overhead here? For dynamic memory allocation we call `malloc` to allocate memory and `free` to release the memory. Also during this process Operating System need to search for available memory from heap and allocate the same as well. To avoid this overhead, he is just suggesting that at the very beginning when your application load and if you know the frequency of probable dynamic memory allocation to a `struct`, you can in advance reserved a pool of memory which will reduce allocation and deallocation of memory overhead  significantly. That is true to a certain extent, if your server is already running a lots of application and processors are very busy you can go for this kind of approach. But there are drawbacks as well. In this case you already reserved a pool of memory from your heap in advance. If not utilized properly it will leads to poor memory management.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the example might be that a `Person` object holds pointers to additional memory. We can see from the `deallocatePerson` function that there are 3 pointers to strings inside the struct:

```
void deallocatePerson(Person *person) 
{
    free(person->firstName);
    free(person->lastName);
    free(person->title);
}
```

It means that to construct a complete `Person` you need several calls to `malloc` (1 for the struct itself and 3 for the strings).

So by saving a complete struct, including its strings, one `getPerson` call replaces *four* calls to `malloc`. That makes it likely to save some execution time.

Otherwise, I would not be surprised if `malloc`/`free` internally holds a similar array or linked list of recently used memory blocks ready to be recycled. If you have just `free`'d a memory block of the correct size, a new call to `malloc` will likely locate that block *very* fast.

Had `Person` been a simple struct without pointers to additional storage, the local caching is not *that* likely to improve performance (but perhaps instead *add* overhead by doing a  linear search).